# Can I create an algorithm using Amazon MWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am working with my team to prep a project for a potential client. We've researched Amazon MWS API, and we're trying to develop an algorithm using the data scraped from this API.

Just want to make sure we understand the research correctly:

Is it possible to scrape data from Amazon.com like the plugins RevSeller or HowMany do? Then can we add that data to a database for use in an algorithm to determine whether or not an Amazon reseller should invest in reselling a product?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am doing a similar project.  I don't know the specifics of RevSeller or HowMany, but another very popular plugin is Amzpecty.  If you use a tool like Fiddler, you can see the HTTP traffic and figure out what it does.  They basically scrape out the ASIN and offer listing ID's on the current page you are looking at and one-by-one call the [Amazon Product Advertising API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html), which is not the same thing as MWS.  Out of that data returned, they produce a nice overlay that tells you all kinds of important stuff.

Instead of a browser plugin, I'm just writing an app that makes HTTP calls based on a list of ASIN's to the PA API and then I can run the results through my own algorithms.  Hope that gives you a starting point.